# How to increase mean of set of numbers

Tags: number-theory, statistics

Lets say:

$X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ... \} $ be a set of Real numbers in range $(R_1, R_2)$ and $m =$ mean of $x$

If I have to increase mean of set $X$ by $3$, each number in the set has to be increase by $3$.
But how to increase mean of set $X$ by $3$, by only changing a subset of X. Is there any mathematical relations as such?

Comment: If there are $n$ elements increase any 1 element by $3n$

Comment: @Sabyasachi I think the problem is the range of the values i.e. $x_1+3n$ may be more than $R_2$

Comment: yeah. more over, what exactly I am looking is that, these numbers shouldn't repeat after transformation!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1, \dots, x_k$ be the subset that does not change and let $x_{k+1},\dots, x_N$ be the subset that does. We have by hypothesis that

$$
{1 \over N} (x_1 + \cdots + x_k) + {1 \over N} (x_{k+1} + \cdots + x_N) = m.
$$

And you want to find some function $f$ such that

$$
{1 \over N} (x_1 + \cdots + x_k) + {1 \over N} f(x_{k+1},\dots,x_N) = m + \sigma.
$$

Using the expression for $m$ above, this becomes

$$
{1 \over N} (x_1 + \cdots + x_k) + {1 \over N} f(x_{k+1},\dots,x_N) =  {1 \over N} (x_1 + \cdots + x_k) + {1 \over N} (x_{k+1} + \cdots + x_N) + \sigma.
$$

$$
\Rightarrow f(x_{k+1},\dots,x_N) = (x_{k+1} + \cdots + x_N) + N \sigma.
$$

As long that is satisfied, you will change the mean by a value of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Now the sum of the $n$elements is $s$ and so $$s=nm$$ Now we want a new mean $M=m+3$ and the new sum $S$ should be $$S=nM=nm+3n=s+3n$$ So you have to add $y_i$ to every element $x_i$ such that
$$\sum y_i=3n$$

## ِAdded

- you can construct another set $y_i$ of elements with mean $3$
- you can add $3$ to every element
- you can add $3n$ to one element